# LOG4J logging is not working on Spark yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, logging, pyspark, log4j, hadoop-yarn

I have build a pyspark application and logging with log4j.

Issue is when I run the spark application in yarn-client mode, the logging is happening but when I run the application in yarn-cluster mode it doesn’t.

I want the log messages to be printed and saved as a file in cluster mode as well.

Already tried

```
Spark-submit —-files option
and setting spark.executor.extrajavaoptions and spark.driver.extrajavaoptions.

My log4j.properties

log4j.rootCategory=INFO,FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender


log4j.appender.FILE.File=/some/path/to/edgeNode/SparkDriver.log

log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wish to provide your custom log4j file, do so by providing it in the spark-submit command. this is so because once spark starts, its own log4j file takes precedence over other log4j configs. 
Provide your log4j file as part of **driver.java.options** flag. If you are running your job in cluster mode instead of client, mention the log4j file in **spark.executors.extraJavaOptions**. Keep in mind the location where the logs are suppoed to be written must be accessible by driver node as well as your compute nodes.

Comment: I’m passing the custom log4j.properties from spark-submit itself.

Comment: It works in - - master yarn and deploy-mode client but doesn’t seem to work in cluster mode.

Comment: Pass the log4j config in —files parameter when in cluster mode